# How to find rows that have duplicate values in the combination of columns in a text file using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

I have a text file and need to print those rows which have duplicate values in the combination of multiple columns. For ex. I would like to find rows that have duplicate values in the combination of state, zip code and continent

```
filename: abc.txt
```

content of the file

```
file starts...
colum|state|zipcode|country|continent
1/1/2|HR|45044|Berlin|Germany
2/1/2|HR|56789||Germany
3/1/2|SR|45044|Baghdad|Asia
4/1/2|BR|45044|France|Europe
5/1/2|HR|45044|Swiss|Germany
file ends...
```

Output:

The program should print below rows as duplicate values are there in the combination of of state, zip code and continent columns

```
1/1/2|HR|45044|Berlin|Germany
5/1/2|HR|45044|Swiss|Germany
```

Answer (score 1):

Use pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("abc.txt",sep="|")
df[df.duplicated((["state","zipcode","continent"]),keep=False)]
```

Documentation: [Pandas Duplicated method](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

Comment: It's working and printing true and false for the records...

Comment: Any idea how to print record also?

Comment: able to do with data.info() function